# notification message in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net

Could you tell me how I can make notification in ASP.NET Web Forms like in ASP.NET MVC, where we have TempData like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(Customer c) {

   TempData["custdetails"] = "Thx for message";

   return RedirectToAction("Index");

}

<div>
 @if (TempData["custdetails"] != null) {

 <p>@TempData["custdetails"]</p>

 }
</div>
```

Comment: You could do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use server tags to input a server value with a javascript alert.

**.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["msg"] = "Page Loaded!!!";       
    }
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("<%= Session["msg"].ToString() %>");
</script>
```